# Struggling to understand the structure of the Facebook API

Tags: c#, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

Ultimately I want to create a desktop app that allows users to update their own status, view status' of their friends, update pics etc. - basically a lot of the functionality the facebook website provides. Through looking through some tutorials and sample projects it seems that an app must be created for the facebook account. Now is this the facebook account of the developer (i.e. mine) - which will provide an API key that will allow any other user to log in?? Does every desktop project need to authenticate the user through a facebook dialog window to take the users' credentials?? Where does OAuth fit into this?? If anyone can shed any light as to the structure of the facebook api and the ways in which I can grant this functionality from say a WPF C# app for example I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: Before complaints of a potentially huge question or too 'vague', my question is specific to the integration/use of the facebook API in desktop applications - not how to then retrieve status feeds etc. I'll work that out myself.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Are you really downvoting me before you even know the answer to that question? Yes, I have read the documentation, I am "struggling to understand" it. I came here for help. Flagged as not-constructive.

Comment: For an app ('your_app') to communicate with Facebook it must connect to a Facebook app ('fb_app') that you create from your (developer) account. your_app uses the fb_ap App ID/API Key as a hook.

As part of developing your_app you need to define what types of access you need to the Facebook details of the user. This is shown to user the first time he/she uses your_app and the user either accepts (authenticates) these or not.

OAuth is a security measure that you don't need to be concerned about too much. Just follow the examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Camden - I really appreciate your response. It's nice when someone actually puts in the effort to trying to answer the question and help out as opposed to scoring cheap upvotes because their rep means so much to them. Post it as answer mate - I'll mark as correct.

Comment: I don't have the ability to "answer", but it's not a problem. Facebook documentation is terrible and my first app was tricky indeed. Once you get your head around stuff and get going it falls into place. Let me know if I can help further, although I can't help with C# aspects.

Comment: Thanks again Camden. My next question may be too specific to C# but I then now need to understand the ways in which I can manage the first time the user logs in in my app and how I there on after save their credentials.

Comment: These things are done automatically. The first time a user uses your_app they will be asked to accept fb_app (which implies authenticating the permissions you wish). If they accept, your_app will have access to their info via fb_app forever, unless they delete the fb_app from their account some point in the future. Edit: maybe we should move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8395/discussion-between-skonjeet-and-camden-kid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Facebook documentation, all desktop apps will need to implement some form of web browser integration, whether embedded within the desktop app or controlled.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> **Desktop Apps**
>
> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit desktop app
>   support. However, if your desktop app can embed a web browser (most
>   desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support embedding
>   browsers), you can use the client-side flow with one modification: a
>   specific redirect_uri. Rather than requiring desktop apps to host a
>   web server and populate the Site URL in the Developer App, we provide
>   a specific URL you can use with desktop apps:
>   https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

Don't worry it took me two solid days of trial and error and re-re-reading of the documentation on authentication to finally "get" it.

Comment: Thanks a LOT DMCS! Just glancing at it now - I think it may be a case of me re-re-reading it too, never dealt with anything like this.